# Apple keyboard key remapping under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, keyboard, keymap, code

I have an Apple keyboard that I simply love. I now hate my regular keyboard at work. I just have a small problem with the Apple keyboard. There is no "insert" key. The one that is usually Insert on regular keyboard is replaced by the "fn" key. I would like to keep the fn functionality, as it is useful with the Fx keys on the top of my keyboard. If I have another key that I want to remap, whoe can I get the code, and then assign the code to the "Insert" function ? I mainly use this key for clipboard stuff (Ctrl-Ins, Shift-Ins), and sometime I have no other option than use the mouse, which is something I want to avoid.

For example, the "Eject" button could be re-assigned, or use the F13..F19 keys, which are not on regular keyboards anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you want the remapping to be done, and which programs you want to detect it. Only in X GUI programs? Then xmodmap is probably enough. Also in command-line programs that you use in a terminal in X? Then xmodmap may be enough, but you may also have to configure your terminal program, and may also have to require your readline configuration (~/.inputrc) and may also have to supply your own terminfo definition and set TERM to this new definition. If you want the remapping to show up in Linux consoles (of the sort you get when you press Ctrl-Alt-F1), you need to do yet other things. Unfortunately, there is no simple, global interface for this.

I summarize some of the interfaces in (a bit) more detail here: [Control-Up,Down,Left,Right as extra keys](https://superuser.com/questions/110622/control-up-down-left-right-as-extra-keys/110711#110711)